# ask for not this element in array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

I would like to do a function except for the current clicked in an array.
Means that I have something like this:

```
cubesmixed = [array, with, 145, elements]
cubesmixed[54].click(function() { 
    for(var i = 0; i < 145; i++) {
    var randomnumber=Math.floor(Math.random()*500000);
    cubesmixed[i].animate({ x: randomnumber, y: randomnumber }, randomnumber, "bounce");
}
```

and I dont want to `cubesmixed[54]` to be animated. How can I say something like
`cubesmixed[i] except 54`

thanks in advance!

Comment: Is there a reason you're using an array of jQuery objects, not just a normal jQuery object containing `x` number of elements?

Comment: if (i != 54) cubesmixed[i].animate({ x: randomnumber, y: randomnumber }, randomnumber, "bounce");

Comment: just use an `if(i == 54) continue` in your function

Comment: If you don’t know stuff as simple as something like `if(i != 54) { /* do stuff */ }` then you should learn some basics first …

Comment: If you want to avoid lots of comparison operations in the loops you could also set up two FOR loops, for all items each side of the selected element. Not such clean code but should in theory be more efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
cubesmixed = [array, with, 145, elements]
cubesmixed[54].click(function() { 
    for(var i = 0; i < 145; i++) {
    var randomnumber=Math.floor(Math.random()*500000);
    if(i!=54)){
        cubesmixed[i].animate({ x: randomnumber, y: randomnumber }, randomnumber, "bounce");
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, as stupid as it is. i didnt think about a if-statement in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

This is off the top of my head, so apologies for inaccuracies:

```
var cubesmixed = $("elementsYouCanClick");

cubesmixed.each(function(idx, element){
    element.click(function() { 
        for(var i = 0; i < 145; i++) {
            if (i === idx) { 
                continue;
            }

            var randomnumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*500000);

            cubesmixed[i].animate({ x: randomnumber, y: randomnumber }, randomnumber, "bounce");
        }
    }
})
```

Not totally sure, but the key idea is to use the `$.each()` function to iterate through the elements, which give you the `idx` to work with.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this could do th trick...

```
cubesmixed = [array, with, 145, elements]
cubesmixed[54].click(function() { 
  for(var i = 0; i < 145; i++) {
    if(cubesmixed[i] == $(this)) continue;
    var randomnumber=Math.floor(Math.random()*500000);
    cubesmixed[i].animate({ x: randomnumber, y: randomnumber }, randomnumber, "bounce");
  }
}
```

**EDIT**

CHange the line `if(cubesmixed[i] == $(this)) continue;` to

```
if(i == cubesmixed.indexOf($(this))) continue;
```

Comment: Unfortunately you can't compare jQuery objects like that, since the `$()` constructor creates a different object each time. In fact `$(this) == $(this)` is always false!

Comment: It still won't work because `.indexOf()` uses the same comparison and `$(this)` is a brand new object that will never be in the array.

Comment: And what about `this` without `$()`? I'm pretty sure that is possible, and i will found how... ^^